# upload multiple files and download and place respective filepath in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using this code for download file same location which I used to upload files but its not working properly.I want to download files folder with in folder and pass path with double slash but files download out side not with in given folder location

```
 String downloadFilepath = "D:\\Test\\Test Documents\\";
    Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    options.addArguments("--test-type");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*.multiple-automatic-downloads", 1);
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: Web browsers cannot allow web code to specify filesystem paths or have direct access to files without user intervention because it would be very insecure. This is likely not possible.

Comment: Thanks Anandha Krishnan can you suggest me any other idea to automate this.

Comment: Can we create a folder and download files one by one each iteration in different folder and change the name of folder at run time